# How To access local repository git from another mac connected to local network

Tags: git, macos, version-control, osx-server

We are working on a team of developers, So we want to add a local git server between us. We are developing on Appcelerator, my Question is how to access the local repository from other apple machines using local network?

Comment: Can you be more precise about your question? Ideally you would do the same as using a remote repo through internet. are you able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) or something similar. They have unlimited private users / repos / groups even for free. Also, you can host it by your own in cloud or dedicated server.

Anyway, I suggest you to read [this chapter in 'Pro Git' book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) to discover all the possibilities. For example, it describes how you can set up your repo with HTTP(S) using Apache.

And, you definitely need to share git repo from user to user, than just share the directory as usual in Mac (I do not know how to do it on Mac, but on Linux you can use Samba, on Windows it is just regular sharing) and then access it like `\\windows-machine\\shared\repo\.git` (that's how Windows shares looks like in network).